# batch insert same contents into multiple text files

Tags: windows, batch

How to batch insert contents of a text file into 500~700 other empty text files inside a folder. 
I don't have much idea about Windows batch. I tried searching Google, but I couldn't find any information about how to do it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`for %X in (\location-of-500to700-empty-text-files\*.txt) do echo type C:\text-file-that-has-desired-contents GT %X`

Does that look good?  Then, take out the word "echo", and replace the "GT" with two greater-than symbols.

`for %X in (\location-of-500to700-empty-text-files\*.txt) do type C:\text-file-that-has-desired-contents >> %X`

The part in parenthesis shows where the empty files are, and the filename after the word `type` is the file that contains the data that you want to be inserted into each empty file.

Note: This will do what you actually asked for.  I feel quite non-confident that you asked for what you were trying to accomplish.  If you're absolutely sure that you asked for the exact right thing, then just customize the file locations.

Comment: tried this one - for %X in (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test\*.txt) do type C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Work\project1.txt >> %X    but it didnt insert the contents of "project1.txt" into all those text files of test folder..

Comment: What happens if you use: `type C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Work\project1.txt` ?  What happens if you use: `for %x in (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test*.txt` ?  What happens if you use: `echo test >> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test-new-file.txt` (assuming that filename did not pre-exist)?  (Then try: `del C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test-new-file.txt` )  If you have up an existing file, and then try that filename instead of `test-new-file.txt` then what happens?  I remain confident in my answer, and wonder if permissions (NTFS security, or UAC) may be causing some effect.

Comment: Hi TOGAM, i shifted files  to other dir for more ease...tried these codes - echo test >> E:\TESTING\test\test-new-file.txt   it creates the text file "test-new-file.txt " with text as "test" inside it , same way for the "del.txt " file too... current code is this -   for %x in (E:\TESTING\test\*.txt) do type E:\TESTING\project1.txt >> %x

Comment: Hi TOGAM, i shifted files  to other dir for more ease...tried these codes - echo test >> E:\TESTING\test\test-new-file.txt   it creates the text file "test-new-file.txt " with text as "test" inside it , same way for the "del.txt " file too... we can be sure its not UAC/NTFS security issue...current code is this -   for %x in (E:\TESTING\test\*.txt) do type E:\TESTING\project1.txt >> %x    converted that "X" in to small "x" but it doesnt insert the text into those files

Comment: I don't see an answer to the first question: What happens if you use: `type E:\TESTING\project1.txt` ?  (I'm sorry, my second question, in prior comment, looks broken.)  How many files are shown if you use: `dir E:\TESTING\test*.txt` What happens if you use: `for %x in (E:\TESTING\test*.txt) do echo %x` ?